# Spring Boot Test: timezone paranormaly deviation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, timezone

I encountered a strange problem.
We are using JPA and it uses the java `Date` inside (even with hibernate 6).
But problem is not in JPA, because I was able to reproduce this deviation without JPA (but can't fix it using another "right" type, because `Data` type in [JPA is using inside always](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f1e099b8e87a9d035f10726d5a8791eecfe5abf2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/LocalDateJavaType.java#L34) if column defnied as `DATE`. And casting to column type later).

RDBMS server and java app working in same UTC timezone. But in tests I see next:

[image]

You see that when I query `current_date()` as a `Date`, I get 2024-02-26 17:00 even though it is February 27 in UTC (timezone in operation system is +7 GMT)

When I run this code not in test env, all is fine:
[image]

I suspect problem inside test contexts. Any ideas how to fix it in tests?

**UPD:** If i change the opetarion system timezone to UTC - then all works fine. Also I tried to specify VM option `-Duser.timezone=UTC` but it had no effect. Strange things.

**UPD:** By using debugger I [reached core here](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-java/blob/c98c084e35ee68249274fcd273644545d90e82a3/clickhouse-jdbc/src/main/java/com/clickhouse/jdbc/internal/ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java#L282) and I see that calendar creating with +7 GMT timezone. WTF? :) If I put this in test controller then it instantiates with UTC tz.

**PS:** I got around the incorrect zone creation by pass extra options to jdbc driver, but I still didn’t understand the true reason for the behavior: `use_server_time_zone=false&client_time_zone=UTC&use_time_zone=UTC` and I not know why the option `use_server_time_zone` really not gets server timezone instead just creates calendar with default client timezone.

Comment: You should be able to `queryForObject<java.time.LocalDate>()` but I don't know if that would solve your issue.

Comment: @k314159 I know. But hibernate using inside old `Data` type even we using `LocalDate` for property. I need explanation for this behavior. Why this is reproducing only in test env?

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)